# How to verify if a packet in Scapy has a TCP layer

Tags: scapy

I want to know how can I verify that a packet I received from the `sr1()` function in Scapy contains a TCP layer, in order to do some treatment on the TCP flags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two options, the `in` operator is one.

```
>>> TCP in pkt
True
>>> if TCP in pkt:
...     # Handle TCP Flags
```

Packet objects in Scapy also have a function called `haslayer()`.

```
>>> pkt = IP()/TCP()
>>> pkt.haslayer(TCP)
1
>>> pkt2 = IP()/UDP()
>>> pkt2.haslayer(TCP)
0
>>> Packet.haslayer.__doc__
'true if self has a layer that is an instance of cls. Superseded by "cls in self" syntax.'
```

Comment: Thank you very much RyPeck for your answer, the problem is that the packet I am going to check is the result of an sr1() command in Scapy so these options didn't work for me unfortunately. I got this error message : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'haslayer'

Comment: Sounds like that's because you aren't actually getting a packet back from `sr1`.

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer can match the protocol at unexpected place. In a robust code you should check the protocol at a particular place in the stack of protocols using the method `layers()`:

```py
>>> pkt1 = IP()/TCP()
>>> pkt1.layers()
[scapy.layers.inet.IP, scapy.layers.inet.TCP]
>>> pkt1.layers()[1] == TCP
True
```

```py
>>> pkt2 = IP()/UDP()
>>> pkt2.layers()[1] == TCP
False
```

The [answer by RyPeck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22096231/320437) will give incorrect results when the communication is encapsulated. For example here is IP encapsulated in IP:

```py
>>> pkt3 = IP()/IP()/TCP()
>>> pkt3.haslayer(TCP)
True
# We got True although the protocol sent over IP is IP, not TCP.

>>> pkt3.layers()[1] == TCP
False
# Using layers() and the position we want to examine [1] we get the correct result.
```